# Center Position a CSS-Animation Playing With rotate(45deg)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```css
#containerScroll {
  height: 5em;
}

scroll {
  transform: translateY(0%) rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.first-scroll {
  left: calc(52.3% - 1em) !important;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite 0.15s;
}

.second-scroll {
  left: calc(52.3% - 1em) !important;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes scrolldown1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="containerScroll">
  <scroll class="first-scroll"></scroll>
  <scroll class="second-scroll"></scroll>
</div>
```

On my end, the output is looking like this:

[image]

This is exactly what I want since the scroll down button is aligned right on top of the text and I achieved this by setting `left: calc(52.3% - 1em) !important;`. On my end, this property is whats making it align perfectly on top of the text.

The problem is that when I zoom out, I'm getting this output:

[image]

As you can see, the scroll button alignment changes and its moved towards the right, and it is because of the `left: calc(52.3% - 1em) !important;` property I'm pretty sure. But I do not want to change or remove this property since this is whats making it align perfectly on `100% zoom`. Is there a way to make this fixed? For example, when I zoom out on the website, the scroll button alignment does not change and remains constant? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `left: calc(50% - 1em) !important`?  That would center it on the page.

Comment: I tried but it did not work

Comment: Can you adjust your example to include the issue? How are you *zooming out* precisely, what steps would one use to recreate the issue you are having and can you recreate the exact environment to recreate your issue?

Comment: Basically, I just zoom out of the website to `25%` and I can see the issue where the scroll button is moved towards the right

Comment: It will be hard to recreate the issue since I have this code in my website and not sure on how exactly to put it in a way so it will give you a chance to recreate the issue

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see it when I zoom in or out.  Yes, it does move some, but trivially.  Is it possible that MY STORY is the one that is moving?

Comment: When you say you're zooming out, your using the browser CNTR + scroll wheel, yes? This is when the element is off center?

Comment: No  the MY STORY is constant but its the scroll button that seems to be moving

Comment: @dalelandry, yes I am using CTRL + scroll

Comment: I would think that if you make the scroll button ***parent container*** absolute and the ***my story*** container relative and a grand parent, no matter how you zoom the elements should stay centered. Then use a flex display on the grand parent element with justify content perhaps?

Comment: can you show please?

Comment: the code for MY STORY is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70538697/alignment-of-element-in-html-css

Comment: Why can't you combine those two snips of code into one and recreate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*That's a really cool animation!*

To perfectly center it, I made the following changes:

- This was being used to center the div, `left: calc(52.3% - 1em) !important;`; I have removed this completely and have used a simple `<center>` tag to center it.
- The animation code itself then runs directly right of center (which is off-center).  You can fix this by moving an element to the left of itself by 50% of its own width with [**`translateX(-50%)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX()).
- Of course, you can't actually use `50%`, because a square box, rotated on its side, increases its width by a factor of about `45%`, which means we need to translateY not by `50%`, but by `66%`.

```css
#containerScroll {
  height: 5em;
}

scroll {
  transform: translateY(0%) rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.first-scroll {
  margin: auto;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite 0.15s;
}

.second-scroll {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes scrolldown1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg) translateX(-66%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotate(45deg) translateX(-66%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg) translateX(-66%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="containerScroll">
<center>
  <scroll class="first-scroll"></scroll>
  <scroll class="second-scroll"></scroll>
</center>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid black;">
<center>&bull;<br>
This dot is perfectly centered.
</center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the CSS just add this property to the `#containerScroll`
position:

```css
fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 90%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: does not work, the scroll button moves with the mouse scroll

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If this works, why don't you click the "Copy snippet to answer" button up above, and add the one line of CSS needed to solve the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Without a full snippit that allows one to fully recreate your issue, I can only attempt to recreate it using the code you have.

You could place the `my-story` and `containerScroll` elements within the ***section title*** together. Then make the *containerScroll* ***position*** ***absolute*** change the **display** to ***flex***. Make its ***top*** position `0` and declare the width 100% and height 10em or what ever you wish its height to be, just make sure the *my-story* element has the same ***top margin*** set in its css as that of your height from the ***containerScroll***.

I have tested this and when I ***ZOOM*** in or out using CNTL + MOUSE WHEEL there is no displacement of the two elements in reference to each other.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --top-dis: 10em; /* use variable so only change once in dynamic locations */
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#containerScroll {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--top-dis);
}

.section-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top:  var(--top-dis);
}

.section-title h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: #45505b;
}

.section-title h2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
}

.section-title h2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0563bb;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.first-scroll {
  left: calc(50% - 1em) !important;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 25px;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite 0.15s;
}

.second-scroll {
  left: calc(50% - 1em) !important;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 80;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  animation: scrolldown1 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes scrolldown1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(0%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20%) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <h2>My Story</h2>
  <div id="containerScroll">
    <scroll class="first-scroll"></scroll>
    <scroll class="second-scroll"></scroll>
  </div>
</div>
```